# Как вызвать прерывание в handler?

Tags: java, android, android-handler, handlers

У меня есть отдельный потоком handler'ом, в котором периодически выполняются действия. Если эти действия не успели выполниться за определенный промежуток времени, их выполнение должно останавливаться и должно начинаться выполнение следующих. Подскажите как можно это реализовать?

Comment: handler.removeCallbacks(myRunnable);

Comment: @shwarz я унаследовал класс handler  и реализовал работу с ним через сообщения, handleMessage, поэтому мне это не подойдет(

Comment: Если вызвать handler.removeCallbacks(null), он удалит все messages и тогда можно post новые. 

А в целом ваша задача это из области реактивного программирования, смотрите на RxJava for Android https://www.google.com.ua/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#safe=active&q=RxJava+for+Android